# win32 GUI not loading properly after adding an edit window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, win32gui

When I build the program in visual studio It takes a long time to build and does not display properly, during this proccess it loads and unloads lots of what appears to be dll files in the console. If I remove the one line that starts with `CreateWindowW(L"EDIT"` the program will run perfectly. I have read through the documentation and I cant find what is wrong with it. Any help is appreciated.

Here is full code

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif 
#include <windows.h>
#include<iostream>

#define file_menu_new 1
#define help_menu 2
#define file_menu_open 3
#define file_menu_exit 4

void AddMenus(HWND hwind);
HMENU hMenu;
void AddControls(HWND hwnd);

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,_In_ PSTR szCmdLine, _In_ int iCmdShow)
{
    // Register the window class.
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"Sample Window Class";

    WNDCLASS wc = { };

    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    //regesters class above with operateing system 
    RegisterClass(&wc);

    // Create the window.
  
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
        L"Learn to Program Windows",    // Window text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,            // Window style

        // Size and position
        500, 200, 800, 500,//WS_DEFAULT OR SOMETHING LIKE THAT

        NULL,       // Parent window    
        NULL,       // Menu
        hInstance,  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
    );

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }


    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);

    // Run the message loop.

    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }


    
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            switch (wParam)
            {
            case file_menu_new:
                MessageBeep(MB_OK);//this creates a sound
                break;
            case file_menu_exit:
                DestroyWindow(hwnd);
                break;
            case file_menu_open:
                MessageBeep(MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            AddControls(hwnd);
            AddMenus(hwnd);
            break;
        }
        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);



            FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1));

            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            break;
        }
    
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

void AddMenus(HWND hwind)
{
    hMenu = CreateMenu();//main menu bar
    HMENU hFileMenu = CreateMenu();//this is a drop down menu for the file part of main menu


    //AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING, 1, L"File");//1 is the identity of this main menu
    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hFileMenu, L"File");//this is how you make it pop up another menu
    AppendMenu(hFileMenu, MF_STRING, file_menu_new, L"New");//adds stuff to hFileMenu with the id of 1
    AppendMenu(hFileMenu, MF_STRING, file_menu_open, L"Open");//adds stuff to hFileMenu with the id of 3
    AppendMenu(hFileMenu, IMFT_SEPARATOR, NULL, NULL);//creates a seperator or a line under open
    AppendMenu(hFileMenu, MF_STRING, file_menu_exit, L"Exit");

    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING, help_menu, L"Help");//2 is the identity of this main menu


    //sets the hMenu to the hwind menu or the main menu
    SetMenu(hwind, hMenu);
}

void AddControls(HWND hwnd)
{
    CreateWindowW(L"static", L"Enter Text here: ", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | SS_CENTER | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT,
        200, 100, 100, 50, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"EDIT", L"Enter Text here: ", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | SS_CENTER,
        200, 160, 100, 50, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Comment: SS_CENTER is not a Edit style. WS_EX_TRANSPARENT is not a style.

Comment: I removed both of those however the problem still persists.

Comment: *"When I build the program in visual studio It takes a long time to build"* - What you describe is neither the compiler nor linker (i.e. not the build that takes long). It is the debugger that's configured to load debug symbols (it even says so). Anyway, there's literally **no** error handling at all. Start by addressing that (either in code or from the debugger).

Answer (score 0):

Add `wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);` and remove `WM_PAINT`. If you don't set a class background you need to handle `WM_ERASEBKGND` or otherwise validate the background color painting.